# Unable to set Gujarati text to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, fonts, localization, jlabel

I want to build Swing application in Gujarati language. I have created properties file and successfully rendered all Gujarati text. but when I set it to `JLabel` it shows square boxes.

Comment: You need to make sure the label is using a `Font` that supports Gujarati characters.

Comment: got it. now working fine

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)  Now you might answer the question yourself or simply delete the question.